# getting a while writing a SOQL query in Javascript button

Tags: soql, javascript

I'm getting an error while writing a SOQL query in onClick Javascript Button.
Below is code

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/42.0/connection.js')} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/42.0/apex.js")} 
var SRIds = []; 
SRIds = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Request__c)}; 

var selectedRecord = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id,Name,OwnerId FROM Request__c WHERE Id = SRIds[0]");
```

I'm getting error while fetching selectedRecord

Comment: What is the error can add it to your question?

Comment: Looking at the code `sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id,Name,OwnerId FROM Request__c WHERE Id = SRIds[0]");` might be error with SOQL query replace above with this `sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id,Name,OwnerId FROM Request__c WHERE Id = \'"+SRIds[0]+"\'");`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code `sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id,Name,OwnerId FROM Request__c WHERE Id = SRIds[0]");` might be error with SOQL query, replace above with this `sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id,Name,OwnerId FROM Request__c WHERE Id = \'"+SRIds[0]+"\'");`

Bind variables are not allowed in Javascript.